# Magento 2 : Compiler gives Class Not Found error

Tags: magento2, magento-community, compiler

I was trying to install Multi-Vendor Marketplace extension from Webkul. I followed these steps:

1. Copied the files to appropriate locations.
2. Ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from root folder. At this point the website became unusable. ALso, the command ended with following statement 'Please re-run magento compile command' .
3. Next, I ran `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` which returned the following error

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException] Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action\Context does not exist

Any help would be highly appreciated in this regard.

Comment: Yes Magento 2.0.2 CE

Comment: Ritwik still if you are getting issues please raise a ticket at http://support.webkul.com/ Thanks

Comment: @Ritwik, can you elaborate which area specifically magento user doesn't have the permssion for this error?

Answer (score 6):

actually, this class really does not exist:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action

I think you should contact the Module Vendor. The class required most likely should be

```
Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context
```

**===UPDATE===**

you should also be able to run the command with verbose output according to the symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#verbosity-levels

try to run:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

This should give you a Stack Trace which could give a hint where exactly the error is

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
I'll check and see if this helps.

Comment: you could try the command in my updated answer to maybe get a clue where exactly the error has its origin

Comment: The stack trace wasn't too helpful as the major useful thing was the class that wasn't found. I've contacted the module manufacturer and they'll get back with a reply tomorrow.

Comment: The issue got resolved. Apparently, the magento user did not have a few permissions. Anyways, thank you for your help