# Compile issue: Class AreProductsSalableInterface does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, setup-di-compile, class-not-found

Having issue in `setup:di:compile` and give below issue

[image]

Already checked: [Magento 2 Setup di Compile Problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/253734/29175)

Magento Vesion: 2.3.1

### **Update 1:**

If i try with command `bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv`, it gives below error

```
[root@server httpdocs]# bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 44 secs 287.0 MiB

In ClassReader.php line 35:

  [ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableInterface does not exist


Exception trace:
 () at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:35
 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassReaderDecorator.php:35
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassReaderDecorator->getConstructor() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Area.php:53
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Area->getList() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:112
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->getDefinitionsCollection() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:87
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->doOperation() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:206
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:893
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:102
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/bin/magento:23

In ClassReader.php line 29:
  
[ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableInterface does not exist


Exception trace:
 () at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29
 ReflectionParameter->getClass() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29
 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassReaderDecorator.php:35
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassReaderDecorator->getConstructor() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Area.php:53
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Area->getList() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:112
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->getDefinitionsCollection() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:87
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->doOperation() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:206
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:893
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:102
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /SITE_PATH/httpdocs/bin/magento:23

setup:di:compile
```

### **Update: 2**

This is result if i try find by:

> find -type f -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nw -e
> 'Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableInterface'

[image]

Comment: Is this happening after an upgrade? Try clearing your redis system cache completely.

Comment: @Jai, Try to delete data from the vendor and then run composer update.

Comment: are you using redis? you can flush it from the redis server cli or simply restart it

Comment: No. we are not using redis. but you can guide me how to flush that. Just command

Comment: you might find this thread helpful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103324/magento-2-compiler-gives-class-not-found-error

Comment: Its not helpful. Just give trace of error.

Comment: If you have a constructor that incorrectly has this class specified in the php docblock, believe it or not, this causes compilation to break

Comment: Its quite possible. please check comment in @oliver answer and if you can help me in more detail please.

Comment: Please share your module zip. i will be check it. I find solution for it.

Comment: this happens with me when MSI modules were disabled and few were enable , here its blog to related MSI module may it help you https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/

Comment: I sorted out yesterday evening. Will post solution soon. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the package `magento/module-inventory-sales-api` doesn't exists yet on Magento 2.3.1

I have projects that are running 2.3.x and 2.4.x and run `find . -name "AreProductsSalableInterface.php"`. Only the project on 2.4.x returned a match which tells me that 2.3.x doesn't have yet that package.

Also the InventorySalesApi started appearing on version 1.1.5
https://github.com/magento/inventory/tree/1.1.5/InventorySalesApi

Comment: This give more details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/msi/InventorySalesApi.html

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you could try setting up the file - proceed with caution!
https://github.com/magento/inventory/tree/1.2-develop/InventorySalesApi/Api
Might need both AreProductsSalableInterface.php and AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface.php

Answer (score -2):

I think it can be one of reason which mentioned below:

1. Maybe a permission issue, try to run compilation command after giving proper permission to var/ pub/ generated folder.

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

2. It may be the composer upgrade/install command not correctly.
   Please run below command

> composer update

3. If you are still facing the same issue then please try to disable all your custom extensions and them and run the below command. If this will work correctly then it is clear that you have an issue with custom themes or extensions.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:comiple

If the above suggestion/solutions don't work, please let me know, I will try to help you.

Thanks

Comment: That 'sudo' has killed me. Sorry

Comment: never do sudo while doing anything with bin/magento

Answer (score -3):

php bin/magento list #If this gives you error check which module causing issue

php bin/magento setup:upgrade # upgrade the setup

php bin/magento setup:di:compile #compilation code

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f #static content display

chown apache:apache -Rf var/ # set permission for apache server cache

chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ # set permisiion to store cache in PUB folder